# Saving micro sign character in a mongo collection

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I'm working on a python script to created a mongo collection based on a MySql db. The problem is with the micro sign character:

```
bson.errors.InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8: '\xb5g'
```

I tried encoding/decoding the value with different codes(utf-8, latin-1, cp1252,iso-8859-2) without success but I always get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: ordinal not in   range(128)
```

This is the code to get the data from the mysql db. The database is the USDA one  [0](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/1?fg=&man=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=&qlookup=):

```
    # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

    import MySQLdb
    mysqldb = MySQLdb.connect(DBCONF)
    cursor = mysqldb.cursor()
    foodid = 1001
    q = (
        ' SELECT nut.Nutr_Val,'
        ' nutdef.Units,'
        ' nutdef.NutrDesc, nutdef.Tagname'
        ' FROM food_des AS f'
        ' JOIN nutrient AS nut ON nut.NDB_No = f.NDB_No'
        ' JOIN nutrient_def AS nutdef ON nutdef.Nutr_No = nut.Nutr_No'
        ' WHERE f.NDB_No = %s'
    ) % str(foodid)
    self.cursor.execute(q)
```

The field with the micro sign character is the nutdef.Units one.

Comment: You'd only get that error when trying to *encode* a bytestring (text not yet decoded to unicode). If you were trying to call `decode` yourself with a specific encoding, you'd get a different `UnicodeDecodeError`. How do you connect to the MySQL database, can we see the code?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OP said they are using mongodb

Comment: @jdi: No, OP said the data comes *from* MySQL, to be stored in Mongo. (*created a mongo collection based on a MySql db*).

Comment: I have a feeling executing `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` before pulling the information from MySQL should resolve this.

Comment: What's in DBCONF? Only host, username and password, or is there other info there as well?

Comment: Worked executing SET NAMES 'UTF-8' like @BurhanKhalid commented. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try decoding the characters as latin-1:

```
a = '\xb5g'
# '\xb5g'
print a
# ?g

b = a.decode('latin-1')
print b
# µg

b
# u'\xb5g'
```

Or you can fix this in your MySQL connection by telling it to use unicode on all CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT fields:

```
MySQLdb.connect(..., use_unicode=True)
```

Comment: The OP stated that they'd already tried that...

Comment: Silly me, I've tried decoding the characters as latin-1 but I thought the decode was in place. The way jdi posted worked perfectly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Apparently not :-)

Comment: @jdi: Heh. Voting to close as Too Localized then; premise of the question is incorrect.